# AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'serialize'

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am getting the error

TypeError:  is not JSON serializable

```
@app.route('/catalog/json')
def catalogJSON():
    categories = session.query(Category).order_by(Category.name.asc())
    return jsonify(Category=[c for c in categories]) code here
```

I then changed the line to

```
return jsonify(Category=[c.serialize for c in categories])
```

Then I got AttributeError: 'Category' object has no attribute 'serialize'

How could I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You will need to say more about your `Category` class, and possibly code a `serialize()` method for it (unless `jsonify(categories)` works).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that soon once I get things working again. I made some database changes and now nothing is working. Thanks for your suggestion and response.